# KeyError con request.sessions

Tags: html, python, django

tengo problemas para entender este código, no es mío pero lo tengo que arreglar. Me aparece el siguiente error:

> KeyError at /presupuestos/step7/
> 'total_manaobra'

La cuestión es que ya revisé todo y sí existe total_manaobra entonces no entiendo porque me marca el error. Incluso en el mismo error de KeyError indica que aparece cuando se manda llamar algo que no está, pero sí lo tengo en todas partes el total_manaobra

Para darles un contexto del programa lo que hace es hacer un registro de un cliente, su carro, sus partes, la mano de obra, carga de imágenes y al final se muestra a modo de preview

> models

```
class Presupuestos(models.Model):
   
   total_manaobra=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
   total_parte=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)


   @property
   def total(self):
       return self.total_manaobra+self.total_parte
   #detalle=models.ForeignKey(Detalle, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.total_manaobra}'
```

> views.py

```
def step7(request):
   technicans = Tecnicos.objects.all()
   step_client = Clientes.objects.get(pk=request.session['client_id'])
   step_vehicle = Carro.objects.get(pk=request.session['car_id'])
   step_parte = reversed(Parte.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:int(request.session['number_parte'])])
   step_manoobra = reversed(ManoObra.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:int(request.session['number_labor'])])
   step_pago = Pagos.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:int(request.session['number_pago'])]
   payment = 0
   for step in step_pago:
       payment += step.cantidad_pagada
   total = int(request.session['total_parte']) + int(request.session['total_manaobra'])
   balance = total - payment
   time=datetime.datetime.now()
   if request.method=='POST':
       presupuestos=Presupuestos()
       presupuestos.resumen=request.session['resumen']
       presupuestos.total_parte=int(request.session['total_parte'])
       presupuestos.total_manaobra=int(request.session['total_manaobra'])
       presupuestos.descuento_parte=request.session['descuento_parte']
       presupuestos.descuentoTotal_parte=int(request.session['descuentoTotal_parte'])
       presupuestos.descuentoTotal_manaobra=int(request.session['descuentoTotal_manaobra'])
       presupuestos.descuento_manaobra=request.session['descuento_manaobra']
       presupuestos.register_time=time
       presupuestos.cliente_id=request.session['client_id']
       presupuestos.carro_id=request.session['car_id']
       print(request.POST['technican_select'])
       presupuestos.tecnicos_id=request.POST['technican_select']
       presupuestos.save()
       return redirect('Presupuestos:step8')
   else:
       return render(request, 'Presupuestos/new-estimate-7-preview.html',
                 {'technicans': technicans, 'step_client': step_client, 'step_vehicle': step_vehicle,
                  'step_parte': step_parte, 'step_manoobra': step_manoobra, 'balance': balance, 'total': total,'time':time})
```

> html

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row" colspan="5" class="border-0 text-end">Discount</th>
  <td class="border-0 text-end">
     <h5 class="m-0">{{request.session.discuentoTotal_manaobra}}</h5>
  </td>
  <td class="border-0 text-end">
     <h5 class="m-0">{{request.session.discuento_manaobra}}</h5>
  </td>
  <th scope="row" colspan="5" class="border-0 text-end">Total</th>
  <td class="border-0 text-end">
     <h4 class="m-0">${{request.session.total_manaobra}}</h4>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Buen día, creo que el error es porque en `step7` estas utilizando `total_manaobra` en un diccionario `request.session` pero en ningún lado se vé que `request.session` ya tenga la llave `total_manaobra`. En la clase `Presupuestos` existe, pero como miembro de la clase.

Comment: te refieres a que no hay un total_manaobra dentro de views.py en el return render?

Comment: No, lo que quiero decir es que tienes un diccionario en el método `step7` y tienes un miembro en la clase `Presupuestos` pero aunque se llamen igual son cosas diferentes. Al parecer tu método `step7` quiere acceder a `request.session['total_manaobra']` pero la llave `total_manaobra` por lo que muestras en el código, no existe dentro del diccionario aún. Revisa el código donde creas `request.session`, seguramente la llave que quieres acceder no ha sido creada.

Comment: gracias!! me ayudó a resolver el problema